# Method of Characteristics nozzle - outputs area ratio?

Tags: aerospace-engineering, propulsion, rocketry

I am designing a rocket engine as my final project at college, and I tried using a [MatLab code developed by youtuber JoshTheEngineer.](https://github.com/jte0419/Rocket_Nozzle_Design) However, after running the code, it seems that the output points and plot show the variation of area ratio (A/A*) along the nozzle length. Is this how the method is supposed to work? My understanding was that the method should provide the nozzle contour, hence the code must output the coordinates of points along the nozzle contour. Is there another manipulation I have to do to obtain the coordinates?

Comment: Ask the youtuber possibly...

Comment: I'd strongly recommend asking the author of the code.  Trying to get others to reverse-engineer software is unlikely to get far.   But **maybe**, if the code is assuming perfectly circular cross-sections, the area ratio directly gives you the radius vs. Z-axis position and you're done.

Comment: How many expansion waves you are using in MOC ?